# Regex: How to prevent multiple whitespace for an input

Tags: jquery

```
$("input[name='ipt1']").on("keypress", function() {
  var regex = new RegExp(//regex syntax);
  if (regex.test(str)) {
       return true;
  }
  else {
       return false;
  }
});
```

Based on the above jquery, what are the most efficient way to filter any double whitespace for the input name **ipt1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use regex for input as simple as double spaces. You can use indexOf as below

```
 $("input[name='ipt1']").on("keyup", function() {
  if($(this).val().indexOf('  ') >= 0) {
   console.log('true');
   return true;
  } else {
   console.log('false');
   return false;
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is (If have double whitespaces - returns true)

```
  var str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"; // one whitespace

  var regex = new RegExp(/\s{2}/, 'g');
  if (regex.test(str)) {
       return true;
  }
  else {
       return false; // retuns false
  }
```

double whitespaces or multiple whitespaces

```
  var str = "Lorem  ipsum dolor sit amet"; // double whitespaces, also works for multiple whitespaces
  var regex = new RegExp(/\s{2}/, 'g');
  if (regex.test(str)) {
       return true; // retuns true
  }
  else {
       return false; 
  }
```